# What's happening with this multidimensional array?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a tiled map by reading from a text file, but instead of creating a multidimensional array with *rowSize*(28) and *columnSize*(19) indexs, it's creating it with *rowSize*(28) and *columnSize*²(361) indexs.

The text file just includes a bunch of 0's and 1's with spaces between them, where there are 19 rows of 28.

```
    try {
        BufferedReader findSize = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line;
        while ((line = findSize.readLine()) != null) {
            if(!line.startsWith("#")) {
                line.split("\\s");
                if(line.length() > rowSize)
                    rowSize = line.length();
                columnSize++;
            }
        }
        grid = new short[rowSize][columnSize];
        findSize.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }

    BufferedReader readTiles;
    try {
        readTiles = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line;
        short rowNum = -1;
        while ((line = readTiles.readLine()) != null) {
            if(!line.startsWith("#")) {
                rowNum++;
                String[] values = line.split("\\s");
                for(String v : values) {
                    for (short y = 0; y < grid[rowNum].length; y++) {
                        grid[rowNum][y] = Byte.parseByte(v);
                        System.out.println(grid[rowNum][y]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        readTiles.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

Not sure if I'm just tired...

Comment: Have you tried debug-printing rowSize and columnSize after the first try block? This will tell you whether the bug is in computing these constants or reading.

Comment: Also, in the first try, you're discarding the value of line.split(), and using line.length() instead. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for your comments; I've never debugged something before because this is pretty much my first real project. I'll debug it later when I'm less tired since I've not had much sleep. By the way, I thought line.split() was used to stop the reader scanning in this case whitespaces. How is line.length() disgarding line.split()?

Comment: The [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method just breaks a string up into an array of smaller strings, dividing it on the string or regex you provide. You're using it correctly later on by splitting a line up into a values array, then iterating through that array (in that case, you might be iterating through each word).

Comment: Does your file, by any chance, have empty lines at the end of it? Any line that does not start with "#" counts as a new column. Also, what is the value of `columnSize` before starting to read than file?